# Digital archive - solution with metadata

Tags: file-management, archiving, metadata, exif

I am in charge of a small digital archive and I am trying to figure out how to manage it.

I have another archive of my owm, but since I am a photographer, I am spoiled by EXIF & IPTC.

The other archive consists of images, video, audio and text in various filetypes.

Is there any solution (program) to add standardized metadata to those files similar to those that images have (title, caption, author, tags, labels,...) and to be able to search using those metadata? Something like Lightroom but for any file type.

I am slightly looking toward Adobe Bridge but I am not sure about the file support there.

How do professional archives manage their data, metadata and sort them?

Comment: Questions asking for a product, service or learning material recommendations are usually off topic here. See [what topics can I ask about here](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Well... what do you propose I do? Is the question stupid or useless? I do not think so. Also I can see quite a lot of questions asking for / about specific software and it can be a meaningful discussion

Comment: Maybe another SE community like [Software Recomendations](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ "softwarerecs.stackexchange.com")  I agree your question is valuable but software recommendations are [off-topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic "what topics can I ask about here") for Super User. This site also discourages discussions however they are welcome in Super User's real-time [web chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=superuser.com "jump to chat.stackexchange.com")    I mean no offense, hope you'll keep contributing.